# Excel 2016 for Mac - converting a matrix to list

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel-2016

I've already seen some answers here but none work on Excel 2016 for Mac.

I want a simple solution to convert a matrix to a list like this:

```
date    city1   city2   cityN
jan1    value   value   value
jan2    value   value   value
```

to

```
date    city    value
jan1    city1   value
jan1    city2   value
jan1    cityN   value
jan2    city1   value
jan2    city2   value
jan2    cityN   value
```

Comment: You've seen answers? Which ones? Did you use them? They didn't work? Why not? What happened? Did you try to fix that?

Comment: Version problems. I used a script on google spreedsheet:

Answer (score 0):

i used a google spreedsheet script:

```
function transformData(){

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();//read whole sheet
 var output = [];
 var headers = data.shift();// get headers
 var empty = headers.shift();//remove empty cell on the left
 var products = [];
   for(var d in data){
     var p = data[d].shift();//get product names in first column of each row
     products.push(p);//store
   }
 Logger.log('headers = '+headers);
 Logger.log('products = '+products);
 Logger.log('data only ='+data);
 for(var h in headers){
   for(var p in products){  // iterate with 2 loops (headers and products)
     var row = [];
     row.push(headers[h]);
     row.push(products[p]);
     row.push(data[p][h])
     output.push(row);//collect data in separate rows in output array
   }
 }
 Logger.log('output array = '+output);
 var ns = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().length+1
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet('New Sheet'+ns,ns).getRange(1,1,output.length,output[0].length).setValues(output);
}
```